# Extract or subset hundreds of columns from a data frame

Tags: r, csv

I need to extract many columns from a dataset. 
I have a very large csv file with thousands of columns and rows, and I read it into R using:

```
mydata <- read.csv(file = "file.csv",header = TRUE,sep = ",",row.names = 1)
```

Each column is a gene name. I know how to extract specific columns from my R data.frame by using the basic code like this:

```
dataset[ , "GeneName1", "GeneName2"]
```

But my question is, how do I pull hundreds of gene names? Too many to type in? They are listed in a txt file. 
I'm new, so please go easy on jargon and abbreviations.

Comment: try `dataset[, 1:100]` or `melt(dataset)`, `?melt`

Answer (score 1):

You can also subset a dataframe in base R like this:

```
# Some dataframe
df = data.frame(a=c(1,2),b=c(1,2),c=c(1,2),d=c(1,2),e=c(1,2))
names(df)

# List of column names to select
colnamelist = c("a","b","c")

# Subset dataframe based on list of wanted columns
df = df[,colnames(df) %in% colnamelist]
names(df)
```

Result will be:

```
> names(df)
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

The logic is: Select from a dataframe `df[row,column]`, where you say the column names to be selected should be in a list `colnames(df) %in% colnamelist`.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I've understood your question correctly.

Assuming your text file looks like this?

```
GeneName1
GeneName2
```

You can read that in using the `readLines()` function:

```
cols <- readLines("name_of_text_file")
```

Which returns `cols` as a vector of those names:

```
> cols
[1] "GeneName1" "GeneName2"
```

Which can then be used to subset the data frame as per your example:

```
mydata[ , cols]
```

Comment: Thank you, Jerb, that worked! However, I get this error if there is a gene in my cols list that is not found in the dataset. Error in `[.data.frame`(sensory, , cols) : undefined columns selected  Do you know what I could add to the script to make it skip over any genes it does not find?

Comment: No probs. You could subset cols with an %in% expression thus:  mydata[, cols[cols %in% names(mydata)]]